# PDF::Create module installation failed using cpan linux command?

Tags: linux, perl, module, cpan

When I tried to install cpan module, i get the following error, i have tried by googling it,am unable to find solution.

```
Catching error: "Can't locate object method \"Create\" via package   \"install PDF\" (perhaps you forgot to load \"install PDF\"?) at /usr/share /perl5/CPAN.pm line 376, <STDIN> line 1.\cJ" at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN.pm line 392, <STDIN> line 1.
CPAN::shell() called at /usr/share/perl5/App/Cpan.pm line 295
App::Cpan::_process_options('App::Cpan') called at /usr/share/perl5/App/Cpan.pm line 364
App::Cpan::run('App::Cpan') called at /usr/bin/cpan line 11
```

Comment: What command did you use? (All signs point to "user error".)

Comment: i used the command as  cpan and then i used the command as install "PDF::Create"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error can be reproduced by doing the following:

```
$ cpan
...
cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v2.10)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]> "install PDF::Create"
Catching error: "Can't locate object method \"Create\" via package   \"install PDF\" (perhaps you forgot to load \"install PDF\"?) ...
```

The problem is you putting quotes around the whole command, apparently.

Solution: Remove the quotes:

```
cpan[2]> install PDF::Create
```

... works fine here.

Also, you can just do `cpan PDF::Create` without entering the cpan shell.